# readfile() behind a proxy?

Tags: php, proxy, readfile

```
public function download_file($link='https://apkpure.co/apk/com.ezfun.p1767.dns_gp1/00b97d3d32a4f8e6cbecff7da5a4af41/1.0/0dfa1365e8e1c70bf2dcf391350a7a77/', $filename='com.ezfun.p1767.dns_gp1_1.0'){

    $extension = 'apk';

    $mime = 'application/octet-stream';

    if( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "MSIE" ) ) {
        header( 'Content-Type: "'.$mime.'"' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.'.$extension );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
        header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
    } else {
        header( "Pragma: public" );
        header( "Expires: 0" );
        header( "Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
        header( "Cache-Control: private", false );
        header( "Content-Type: ".$mime, true, 200 );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.'.$extension);
        header( "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" );
    }

    readfile( $link );

}
```

i need readfile download a apk file, but i cant visit this website directly, i need a proxy.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to download file by proxy using curl:

```
function download_file($url, $filename) {

    $proxy = 'Proxy IP ADDRess'; //128.114.63.15:3128
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
    header('Expires: 0'); // no cache
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()) . ' GMT');
    header('Cache-Control: private', false);
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '.apk"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($response)); // provide file size
    header('Connection: close');
    echo $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found readfile() is not support bind a proxy, if you want , you must find a way to set proxy in base. someone said use apache, but i havent trid.

finally another function file_get_contents() solve my problem.

here is my code :

```
public function download_file($link='https://apkpure.co/apk/com.ezfun.p1767.dns_gp1/00b97d3d32a4f8e6cbecff7da5a4af41/1.0/0dfa1365e8e1c70bf2dcf391350a7a77/', $filename='com.ezfun.p1767.dns_gp1_1.0'){

    $aContext = array(
        'http' => array(
            'proxy' => 'tcp://192.168.10.3:18118',
            'request_fulluri' => true,
        ),
    );
    $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

    $sFile = file_get_contents("https://apkpure.co/apk/com.wepie.snakeoff/6fbde5c9d65e72d4d014f9bf654bfe47/2.0/984e0be4d6a84965544692bc30487837/", False, $cxContext);

    $path = file_put_contents(public_path().'/application.snakeoff.apk', $sFile);

    echo $path;

}
```

the file_put_content will returns the number of bytes that were written to the file, or FALSE on failure.